# TYPO3 "private" page for modifications

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I had a PHP Website which had a "admin.php" page, where I could set some special settings like activating an infobox e.g.

Now I am rebuilding my Website with TYPO3 and I am asking myself, how I have can make something like a "admin.php" where I can do settings.

Can someone help me with that? I hope I could explain my issue so you understand it, otherwise please tell me if you didn't get the point of it!

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 is a **Content Management System**, the **M** stands for what you are searching for! As user with administrator role, there are multiple modules where you can configure extensions, change output of things, ....

So it could be the *Constant Editor* what you are looking for, otherwise ask a more concrete question.

Comment: thank you for answering! I have a textfield where i can set the percentage for offers. I want to know how to implement something like that into TYPO3. Like there is a Page "Configurations" and there i can set the percentage, allow user comments to be displayed on the Website and so on

Comment: create an extension, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/CreateNewExtension/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

The BackEnd, which you access by `domain.tld/typo3/` is the place where all modifications to the FrontEnd output is done. That includes the normal content of text and images or other Content-Elements like plugins, records like news or tt_address and of course pages to get the structure.
Here an editor also decides the visibility of content.

The BackEnd is also the area where the behaviour of the site is configured, mostly with TypoScript. With TypoScript you can configure the behaviour of Plugins or the general rendering of pages.

maybe you had all configurations in one admin.php file, in TYPO3 the configuration might be distributed to different places, but as there are very much possibilities to configure there are also much places to configure.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you have some tips how to start with that? I can't imagine how i can make such things in the Backend yet. Because in the admin.php file i had comments of users which i could activate (set flags in the db) by clicking onto them e.g. How would i realize something like that with Typo3 in the Backend?

Comment: you may start with some tutorials how to work with TYPO3, like the official videos (https://typo3.org/documentation/videos)